# What does this line of code does in C programming?

Tags: c, data-structures

code  :-

`pu->queue[ pu->rear = (pu->rear + 1) % pu->size ] = x;`

I know the workings of the queue but i'm just confused about the assigning variables inside the index value of the arrays. Is this a good practice? Does that work? I can't compile because i don't have the full code.

Edit :- Solved. but that code does compile. now that i have access to the code itself, it compiles without warnings.

Comment: The code does not compile, because `pu-rear` is not an lvalue, and can thus not be assigned to.

Comment: @EOF, Fixed; it's obviously a typo for `pu->rear`

Comment: @ikegami Why fix a question that obviously needs closing?

Comment: Why does it "obviously need closing?"

Comment: Well, if you can't understand it, it's probably not good practice. ;-) Someone was being fancy when they wrote this. It will probably work, though.

Comment: That line of code is near-pointless. `pu->rear = (pu->rear + 1) % pu->size;` is the only functional part. The array subscripting is meaningless, as there is no assignment to the cell element, nor any apparent usage of any resulting value from the overall expression. Any semi-intelligent compiler would flag this line for "expression result unused". And for the record, I'm continually befuddled how "typos" are introduced from code that supposedly (a) compiles, and (b) should be copy/pasted, not hand-entered, into a question.

Comment: @EOF, It's a basic question, but does it really need closing? Even with some research, the answer might not be easy to find for a novice.

Comment: @ikegami yes i tried on google. i used simplier expressions like a[x=y] but didn't find anything.

Comment: @EOF the code does compile. i just asked my professor to send me the code and it works well without warnings.

Comment: You would look up the [C assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment). The linked page says "*Assignment also returns the same value as what was stored in `lhs` (so that expressions such as `a = b = c` are possible). The value category of the assignment operator is non-lvalue (so that expressions such as `(a=b)=c` are invalid).*" But it might not be obvious to the less educated that this is relevant

Comment: Re "*the code does compile*", What you originally posted did not. This is the code to which EOF was referring

Comment: @ikegami it was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's short for

```c
pu->rear = (pu->rear + 1) % pu->size;
pu->queue[pu->rear]
```

---

An expression returns a value, and can thus be used within a larger expression. A statement doesn't return a value, so it can't be used in an expression (without a `do { }`-style construct). An expression can be usually be used as statement (where its returned value is discarded).

In some languages, assignments are statements. In others, assignments are expressions. In C, assignments are expressions. They return the value that was stored. As such,

```c
pu->queue[ pu->rear = (pu->rear + 1) % pu->size ]
```

is short for

```c
pu->rear = (pu->rear + 1) % pu->size;
pu->queue[pu->rear]
```

The code appears to be implementing a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: thanks sir. This is the info i really needed. Question solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to tackle this part of the question:

> Is this a good practice?

No, for these reasons:

- It's hard to understand at a glance, because you have three different things happening - two assignments and a subscript operation;
- This style can make code hard to analyze in a debugger - there's no good way to set a breakpoint to verify the computation of the new value of `pu->rear` before using it to subscript into the array.

This *specific* instance isn't too bad, but it's not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code deals with a circular queue. This expression

```
pu-rear = (pu->rear + 1) % pu->size
```

determines the index `pu-rear` in the array `pu->queue` where a new data will be written.

For example if you have an array declared like

```
T a[2];
```

and the initial index i equal to `-1` then the first element will be written at the position ( i + 1 ) % 2 that is at the position 0.

The next element when i is equal to 0 (after the previous operation) will be written at the position ( i + 1 ) % 2 that is at the position 1.

The third element when i is equal to 1 will be written again at the position 0

```
( i + 1 ) % 2 == ( 1 + 1 ) % 2 == 0
```

That is when the end of the array is reached new elements are added at the array beginning anew.

To make it more clear consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    int a[N];
    int i = -1;
    
    for ( int value = 0; value < 10; ++value )
    {
        a[ i = ( i + 1 ) % N ] = value;
        
        printf( "i = %d, a[%d] = %d\n", i, i, a[i] );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
i = 0, a[0] = 0
i = 1, a[1] = 1
i = 2, a[2] = 2
i = 0, a[0] = 3
i = 1, a[1] = 4
i = 2, a[2] = 5
i = 0, a[0] = 6
i = 1, a[1] = 7
i = 2, a[2] = 8
i = 0, a[0] = 9
```

Comment: Didn't the OP already say he understood the queue's workings?

Comment: @RobertHarvey which country do we refer to here?

Comment: always open for different explanations though ;)

Comment: @thetrickster Thanks. You are an adequate person.:).